# New environment for boxed equations

Tags: errors, equations, environments

I would like to define new environments to highlight certain equations in some way. For example, I would like a highlighted equation to appear in red text or with a box around it. I have the red text version working but the boxed version is giving me a pair of related errors:

> Missing } inserted. \begin{boxedeq*}
>
> Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{boxedeq*}

Since there are unmatched braces in the before and after sections of the new environment, it is my understanding that I need to [use `\bgroup` and `\egroup` instead of `{` and `}`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros#Unmatched_braces). This works for the red text case but the errors indicate that it isn't working for the boxed case (a "missing" `}` is inserted in the before section and an "extra" `}` is found in the after section).

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}

% equation/equation* environments highlighted in red
\newenvironment{higheq}{\textcolor{red}\bgroup\begin{equation}}{\end{equation}\egroup}
\newenvironment{higheq*}{\textcolor{red}\bgroup\begin{equation*}}{\end{equation*}\egroup}

% equation/equation* environments highlighted with box
\newenvironment{boxedeq}{\begin{equation}\boxed\bgroup}{\egroup\end{equation}}
\newenvironment{boxedeq*}{\begin{equation*}\boxed\bgroup}{\egroup\end{equation*}}

\begin{document}
\begin{higheq}
\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1
\end{higheq}

\begin{equation}
\boxed{\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1}
\end{equation}

\begin{boxedeq*}
\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1
\end{boxedeq*}

\end{document}
```

And here is the output:
[image]

How do I avoid this error?

Comment: `\boxed\bgroup...\egroup` is not at all equivalent to `\boxed{...}`. In the former case the argument to `\boxed` is `\bgroup`. You should look at the `empheq` package.

Comment: @egreg So how do I get the equivalent of `\boxed{...}`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just in case you are interested in fancier boxes, [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) can be used and it nicely interacts with `empheq`. A little example showing some possibilities:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
  highlight math style={
    enhanced,
    colframe=NavyBlue!70!black,
    colback=NavyBlue!10,
    boxrule=1pt,
  }
}

\newenvironment{boxedeq}
  {\empheq[box=\tcbhighmath]{equation}}
  {\endempheq}
\newenvironment{boxedeq*}
  {\empheq[box=\tcbhighmath]{equation*}}
  {\endempheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{boxedeq}
\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1
\end{boxedeq}

\begin{boxedeq*}
\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1
\end{boxedeq*}

\tcbset{
  highlight math style={
    enhanced,
    colframe=Maroon,
    colback=Peach!10,
    arc=4pt,
    boxrule=1pt,
  drop fuzzy shadow
  }
}

\begin{boxedeq}
\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1
\end{boxedeq}

\begin{boxedeq*}
\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1
\end{boxedeq*}

\tcbset{
  highlight math style={
    enhanced,
    colframe=black,
    colback=white,
    arc=0pt,
    boxrule=1pt,
  }
}

\begin{boxedeq}
\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1
\end{boxedeq}

\begin{boxedeq*}
\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1
\end{boxedeq*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, way to go above and beyond!

Answer (score 10):

Saying `\boxed\bgroup<tokens>\egroup` is not the same as `\boxed{<tokens>}`. You can't use `\bgroup` as a substitute for an argument delimiter.

You accomplish your need with the `empheq` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

\newenvironment{boxedeq}
  {\empheq[box=\fbox]{equation}}
  {\endempheq}
\newenvironment{boxedeq*}
  {\empheq[box=\fbox]{equation*}}
  {\endempheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{boxedeq}
\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1
\end{boxedeq}

\begin{boxedeq*}
\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1
\end{boxedeq*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But what's the difference between `\textcolor{red}{<tokens>}` and `\boxed{<tokens>}` such that `\bgroup` and `\egroup` work for the former but not the latter?

Comment: @Null With color you're lucky because of how the command is implemented.

Comment: So is there a better way to implement the red equation environment?

Comment: @Null Your code is pretty much equivalent to saying `\color{red}\begin{equation}` in the “begin part” and `\end{equation}` in the “end part”.